# Get absolute path from dentry_path_raw

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, symlink

I try to get the target of symlink dentries in a kernel module, i.e. the dentry on which my dentry points.

I use this approach:

```c
int print_dentry(struct dentry *d) {
    struct path p;
    char *buffer, *path_name;
    int ret;
    buffer = (char *)__get_free_page(GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!buffer)
        return -ENOMEM;
    path_name = dentry_path_raw(d, buffer, PAGE_SIZE);

    if (IS_ERR(path_name))
        printk(KERN_ERR "ERR");

    if ((ret=kern_path(path_name, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &p))) {
        printk("kern_path returned %d for path_name \"%s\", inode %ld\n", ret, path_name, d->d_inode->i_ino);
        return 0;
    }
    printk_once(KERN_INFO "Path %s -> dentry_uid %ld\n", path_name, p.dentry->d_inode->i_ino);
    free_page((unsigned long)buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

However, `dentry_path_raw` doesn't return the absolute path, but a path relative to the vfsmount.

Hence I get errors like this when there is a vfsmount e.g.

```
kern_path returned -2 for path_name "/self", inode 4026531841
```

Which corresponds to /proc/self

```bash
ls -ial /proc/self 
4026531841 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0  5 déc.  04:28 /proc/self -> 1341
```

Is there a way to get the absolute path so that I can give it to `kern_path()`? Or maybe another approach to follow the symlink and get the associated dentry?

I don't think I can use directly `d_absolute_path` or `prepend_path` since they take as input a `struct path*` or a `char*` and I only have a access to a `struct dentry*` or a `char*`

Comment: Given that a filesystem could be bind-mounted in several places at the tree, and that different processes can have different roots, a dentry alone is not sufficient - the caller of `print_dentry()` should provide the `vfsmount` that constitutes the root mount of the absolute path. And you'll need to call an API that accepts a root mount, e.g. `filename_lookup()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1/source/fs/d_path.c#L330), it seems that when you call `dentry_path_raw()` it actually calls another function that does the following:

```cpp
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 */
/*
 * Write full pathname from the root of the filesystem into the buffer.
 */
static char *__dentry_path(const struct dentry *d, struct prepend_buffer *p)
{
    const struct dentry *dentry;
    struct prepend_buffer b;
    int seq = 0;

    rcu_read_lock();
restart:
    dentry = d;
    b = *p;
    read_seqbegin_or_lock(&rename_lock, &seq);
    while (!IS_ROOT(dentry)) {
        const struct dentry *parent = dentry->d_parent;

        prefetch(parent);
        if (!prepend_name(&b, &dentry->d_name))
            break;
        dentry = parent;
    }
    if (!(seq & 1))
        rcu_read_unlock();
    if (need_seqretry(&rename_lock, seq)) {
        seq = 1;
        goto restart;
    }
    done_seqretry(&rename_lock, seq);
    if (b.len == p->len)
        prepend_char(&b, '/');
    return extract_string(&b);
}
```

And everything seems to be in the description of this function. It writes the full path into the buffer, not in its return value, which share it's return with `dentry_path_raw()`.

So, you should use the value pushed into your `buffer` instead of `file_name`, which is just the name returned by the function `dentry_path_raw()`.

Note: `dentry_path_raw()` doesn't resolve symlinks, if you really want to resolve them you should probably use `dentry_path()` instead.

All these functions are available since linux v2.6.26/v2.6.38